# Using super with inheritance from builtin type - different results with list

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, super

I'm trying to make a custom type that will behave just like builtin type but will also hold some additional information about the value.
Code is like:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()
```

Then that would work:

```
addi_into = {x:y, ...}
base = (Value, int)
attr = {**dict(Value.__dict__), **addi_info}
_type = type('name', base, attr)
var = _type(1)
```

It behaves just as it was int, except I get access to additional info and methods in Value.

Only thing that does not work is when I do this:

```
addi_into = {x:y, ...}
base = (Value, list)
attr = {**dict(Value.__dict__), **addi_info}
_type = type('name', base, attr)
var = _type(['some', 'list'])
```

It breaks.
There's no error, just that the list is empty.

Value methods and attributes are in place as expected.

The workaround is to have a special case for list,

because `super().__init__(value)` breaks it for other values:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value):
        if type(value) == list: super().__init__(value)
        else: super().__init__()
```

Each type constructor (int, str, list...) I testef requires the value to be the first parameter so that kinda confuses me.

Can you suggest a more elegant way to implement this?

Or explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable types (e.g. `str`, `int`) don't have their own `__init__`, and get the one inherited from `object`. Instead, they are fully initialized inside `__new__`. For these types you can omit the call to `super().__init__()` entirely and still get the correct result.

To make this generic, you should probably check if `__init__` of the base class is different from `object.__init__`, and only call it then.